# How to remove contours with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV's drawCountours function to remove only the boxes and preserve the text. However, I'm facing an issue where some of the boxes share pixels with the text, resulting in the removal of characters as well. The image I'm working with is this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSeIu.png).

Can you help me with any suggestions to remove the boxes?

Thank you!

```
import cv2

def contour_height(contour):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return h

image = cv2.imread("sample.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)

# Applying threshold
threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
edges = cv2.Canny(threshold, 50, 200)

# Finding and sorting contours based on the contour area
contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=contour_height, reverse = True)

# Display
cv2_imshow(cv2.drawContours(image, contours[:35], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2))
```

The result is this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPX7g.png)

Comment: Please make sure that your code sample is executable.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Now it runs!

Comment: Post the original image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra you can find it in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUzIp.png

Comment: That is not the original.

Comment: I included the original image in the description

Comment: It looks to me that your boxes go between letters. So the box removal should have not affect on pytesseract being able to read the letters once the boxes are removed.